# SAP Crystal reports versions information?

Tags: crystal-reports

Someone knows where can I get information about the features or a log of changes between SAP Crystal Reports versions?, because I want to get information about SAP Crystal Reports 13.0.20 and the latest version of SAP Crystal Reports that I think it is SP31 and compare them to know:
-Does SAP Crystal Reports SP31 requires a license compared to 13.0.20 version
-What new features does the latest version have compared to 13.0.20 version
-It is backwards compatible?
-etc...

Comment: I would recommend contacting SAP support with these questions.

Comment: @R.McMillan Yeah, I went to SAP forum and they gave me good info :D